# Как правильно сделать код

Tags: запрос, php, mysql

Подскажите как правильно сделать код

```
$site_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = '$pr'");
```

Подскажите как $pr изменить на

```
$data['pr']
```

Что бы без ошибок

Answer (score 5):

```
$site_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = '".$data['pr']."'");
```

Comment: Благодарю, очень помог код

Answer (score 2):

Можно еще и так:

```
$pr = $data['pr'];
$site_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = '$pr'");
```

Или так

```
$site_query = mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = '%s'", $data['pr']));
```

Ну а еще лучше так (особенно если $data['pr'] получена извне:

```
$pr = mysql_real_escape_string($data['pr']);
$site_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = '$pr'");
```

или

```
$site_query = mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = '%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($data['pr'])));
```

Comment: А подсказать можете, можно сделать в базе строчку data что бы авто записывал дату также как id каждый раз новый и при добавление новой строки что бы дата новая создавалась

Comment: Можно добавьте для свойства DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP или выполните запрос к таблице:

     ALTER TABLE `Имя_таблицы` CHANGE `datа` `data` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: http://screeny.ru/52fbb218f69e6e0c6400ce29 - подскажите что тут выбрать

Comment: По умолчанию -> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP (правда не уверен, что он в этой программе так называется, сам я использую phpmyadmin)

Comment: А это что ?, тоже phpmyadmin

Comment: Всё сделал что ты сказал выдаёт ошибку #1067 - Invalid default value for 'data'

Comment: А ну да, извините, надо изменить еще и тип на TIMESTAMP, тогда при добавлении новой записи в базу будет автоматически записано текущее время